# how to save checkbox value after page load in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, checkbox

How can I save the state of checked checkbox and use the value after a page load.
With the below mentioned code I click on a checkbox, but after clicking on calculate button my page loads and the checkbox gets unchecked.

This is my code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("F1372B03C0090002_01082008__ctl2_F1372B03C0090002_01082008C2")).click();
```

This is the Html form for checkbox

```
INPUT onclick="document.all('hdnIsValueChanged').value=1; if (F1372B03C0090002_01082008__ctl2_HiddenBox_F1372B03C0090002.value==0) {F1372B03C0090002_01082008__ctl2_HiddenBox_F1372B03C0090002.value=1;};" id=F1372B03C0090002_01082008__ctl2_F1372B03C0090002_01082008C2 CHECKED type=checkbox value="" name=F1372B03C0090002_01082008:_ctl2:F1372B03C0090002_01082008C2
```

Answer (score 0):

Did u tried to store their values in variables right before click calculate button?

After reload, u can assign them properly values.

Comment: No i'l try that

Comment: Not working even after storing the value in variable.                                                                                      
WebElement checkBox=driver.findElement(By.id("F1372B03C0090002_01082008__ctl2_F1372B03C0090002_01082008C2"));
  checkBox.click();

Comment: boolean value = diver.findElement(By.id("F1372B03C0090002_01082008__ctl2_F1372B03C0090002_01082008C2")).isSelected();

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use below code snippet to chek the state of checkbox and click on it.

```html
WebElement checkBox1 = driver.findElement(By.id("F1372B03C0090002_01082008__ctl2_F1372B03C0090002_01082008C2"));
  boolean checkboxState = checkBox1.isSelected();
  if (checkBox1.isSelected() == true) {
   System.out.println("Check box is selected");
  } else {
   System.out.println("Check box is not selected");
   checkBox1.click();
  }
```

Comment: I tried this...No luck. When i click on Calculate the checkbox gets unchecked...How can i use cookies or local storage to save the state of checkbox so that it fetches the value after the page loads

Answer (score 0):

You should store the values inside a Map before clicking on Calculate, create a custom click so it adds the item to the map, here is a simple example:

```
private HashMap<String, String> values;

// this method will click on the element(checking it) and use store method
public void checkAndStore(final WebElement element) {
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(element).click(element).build().perform();
    addToMap(element);
}

// here we store the id of element as key to the map and value as value
private void addToMap(WebElement element) {
    values.put(element.getAttribute("id"), element.getAttribute("value"));
}

// this is your getter
public HashMap<String, String> getMyMap() {
    return this.values;
}

// and now you can click as many checkbox as you want and get the result aftewards:
@Test
void myTest() throws Exception {
    checkAndStore(driver.findElement(By.id("1")));
    checkAndStore(driver.findElement(By.id("2")));
    checkAndStore(driver.findElement(By.id("3")));
    driver.findElement(By.id("myCalculateButton")).click();
    System.out.println(getMyMap().entrySet());
}
```